# Which harmony flag for default parameters in nodejs v4

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using node.js v4.0.0 and am trying to get some code working without the need of transpiling it first. While most is working, I can't use

```
import
```

which might be because of the not finalized stage, but I also can't find a flag that enables it. I've tried all of them:

```
--harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
  --harmony_array_includes (enable "harmony Array.prototype.includes" (in progress))
  --harmony_regexps (enable "harmony regular expression extensions" (in progress))
  --harmony_proxies (enable "harmony proxies" (in progress))
  --harmony_sloppy (enable "harmony features in sloppy mode" (in progress))
  --harmony_unicode_regexps (enable "harmony unicode regexps" (in progress))
  --harmony_reflect (enable "harmony Reflect API" (in progress))
  --harmony_destructuring (enable "harmony destructuring" (in progress))
  --harmony_sharedarraybuffer (enable "harmony sharedarraybuffer" (in progress))
  --harmony_atomics (enable "harmony atomics" (in progress))
  --harmony_new_target (enable "harmony new.target" (in progress))
```

(useless to say that I didn't use regexps for it... :))

While I get the reason for import, I don't see why default parameters are failing as they seem to be finalized and I can't find a flag which seems to handle it.

Is there a flag for import and default parameters?

The code that doesn't work is

```
class foo extends bar {
    constructor(options = {})
    ....
}
```

error is

> unexpected `=` illegal token

Comment: *"Also doesn't work with babels polyfill."* Polyfills are for *APIs*, not syntax. You cannot polyfill syntax.

Comment: Can we please not ask a new question about with `--harmony` every time a node version is released? All these questions are becoming irrelevant in the future. Read the changelogs instead: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/. We used to have a nice close reason for these kind of questions...

Comment: I did read them @FelixKling, but your right - isn't the best question to ask but I really couldn't find something and been tricked by https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters saying it was finalized.

Comment: @michael: "Finalized" does not mean "implemented".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Node 4 uses the version of V8 that shipped with Chrome 45 - and V8 v4.5.103.3 doesn't ship with default arguments, even behind a flag.  Default arguments landed in the version of V8 that shipped with Chrome 49 and will be in Node 6+.

Comment: Thanks! Is it the same for import?

Comment: `import` [isn't even under development right now](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569) due to specification work that still needs to be done.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain so I can improve the answer?

Comment: Node surely doesn't employ Chrome.

Comment: Correct - I've amended the answer to make it clear(er) that I'm referring to the version of V8 that shipped with Chrome 45 and I'm just using chromestatus as a convenient place to track the progress of the underlying V8 engine.  Let me know if I can do anything further to improve the answer!

Comment: Note that V8 and Chrome are developed as independent projects, so they have different versioning.

Comment: Updated to use the correct version number of V8 shipped with Node 4.0.0

Answer (score 6):

the flag is : `--harmony_default_parameters`

Comment: Not for node 4 that the OP is using there isn't.